# FB Share and picture problem

Tags: facebook, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Hi I have added following meta tags to my website:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Pro Commerce d.o.o."/>
<meta property="og:admins" content="19292868552"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Preglej najboljšo spletno stran s poslovnimi in promocijskimi darili!"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.procommerce.si/design/images/logoFB.jpg"/>
```

Before that meta for image was pointing to a different image (not to http://www.procommerce.si/design/images/logoFB.jpg)... Now whenever I click Share button I get the old images... It doesn't refresh...

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook caches this information. see the Facebook URL Linter to see what facebook sees, and to reset the cache: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: I thought it is smth with cache ... Thanks!

Comment: @Rufinus - how do you reset the cache? I don't see this on the site

Comment: as soon as you use the tool the cache is refreshed with the new data.